# How do you find a seed for nextFloat() that returns a number above a threshold several times?

Tags: java, random

How would I find a seed for nextFloat() that would return a number above a threshold, say `nextFloat() > 0.8`, several times? Maybe five times in a row? Of course 0.8 and 5 are examples, and I know there are a very large number of solutions, but I don't know how I would even go about finding a single one. A lot of the math governing the random numbers `next()` returns goes way over my head. All help is very appreciated!

Comment: The easiest way would be to run  `nextFloat` until you get the sequence you want - then you know what seed to use to reproduce that sequence. Of course if your condition has a very low probability (say 100 numbers above 0.999999 in a row), it may take a while or even never stop if the probability is zero.

Comment: Just do what's call rejection sampling. If you want a random number, but with some odd restraint, just generate regular uniform random numbers and throw away any that don't meet the restraint.

Comment: Why don't you just add 0.8 to the result of nextFloat()? Or what is the real goal you want to achieve with the random numbers?

Comment: What's your reason for wanting such a thing?  Cherry picking a low probability sample will bias any statistics you might be generating.  I'm not saying there aren't valid applications (such as [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling), but the invalid uses far outnumber the valid ones.